# Successful implementations of Customer Care Accelerator?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Do you know of any successful implementations of the Customer care Accelerator framework for Dynamics CRM 2011? The powerpoint demos look great, but when I try to find information on this I really don't find a lot.

The reason I ask is because one of my customers wants me to look into this. The purpose is to create a Composite UI tighlty integrated with Dynamics CRM.

After downloading the CCA I tried to compile the code but it requires a missing DLL that is not distributed with CCA. It turns out this is an old version of WPFCAB which I understand is no longer maintained (http://wpfcab.codeplex.com/) but is now part of the Smart Client Contrib (also, from 2008). My colluegue believes this too is old and has been replaced by PRISM.

My question is simply, are there any (successful) implementations of CCA for CRM 2011 and is it actively maintained?

Answer (score 0):

Historically I've found most of the MS-provided Accelerators to be rather unsatisfying: Either  too incomplete, or very feature-complete but inflexible. There's a few exceptions (in CRM v4 the Event accelerator provided a nifty set of pre-configured entities, but the portal side was junk) but overall I think they're a good demo of what MSCRM is capable of but not in a customer-usable scenario.

For CRM2011 the Accelerators I've tried using have just taken the old CRM4 code and pushed it through a 4>2011 converter with little or no tidy-up.

If you're a competent coder, I'd skip the accelerator and write something from scratch either using the MS SDK or in HTML/JavaScript using the oData APIs.

(Note: I'm a CRM consultant for an MS partner, and I do next to no server-side coding - a developer may have a different take on this)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are many successful implementations of CCA (Customer care Accelerator). You can yourself try installing it from the links given below. Here are a few links that you can check http://crmmongrel.blogspot.in/2011/08/customer-care-accelerator-for-dynamics.html http://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2012/08/07/tips-to-install-cca-for-crm-2011.aspx

Please note - you must do this from the server where CRM is installed.

PS -  This also works for CRM 2013.

Hope this helps.